# Java inline assembly transferring variables

Tags: java, assembly, inline

Hello I'm trying to do simple java code with inline assembly. In asm procedure I want to do some operations on java variables here are my codes

```
public class Add {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          int a=5;
          int b=4;
          int c=0;

            System.loadLibrary("native");
            (new Add()).nativeCode();


    }

    public native void nativeCode();
}
```

And Asm procedure

```
global _Java_Add_nativeCode
section .text
_Java_Add_nativeCode:
mov eax, a
mov ebx, b
add eax,ebx 
mov c,eax
```

I'm trying to do operations on variables like in C++ but Nasm gives me an error symbol 'a' undefinied etc. Is there any way to do operation on variables declared in java in ASM procedure?

Comment: Local variables are only accessible within the scope of the block defining the variable. Code outside of that scope must be passed the values of those variables, e.g. as method parameters.

Comment: If that's NASM, you're adding the addresses, not the values.  Use `mov eax, [a]` / `add eax, [b]`, etc.  Assuming you had static/global symbols with those names, which you don't.  `mov eax, a` is `mov eax, imm32` with the address of `a`.  `mov c, eax` is a syntax error.

Comment: And I assume you're talking about MSVC's `asm { }` block syntax?  Inline-asm is special, and can use C identifiers even for locals.  MSVC's implementation kind of sucks though, because AFAIK you can only get data into/out of asm blocks through memory, not in registers, so short `asm{}` blocks without loops waste a bunch of instructions on data movement and incur a lot of extra latency.  I assume this is part of why their inline asm syntax is not available for x86-64.  (And maybe because intrinsics are the better way to do 90% of what inline asm used to be good for.)

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a virtual variable.  The only way to do this at the moment is to implement a method call in C via JNI.  I suggest you use javah to generate C code and use `asm` from that.  Note: this will be many time slower than doing the same thing in Java (and many time more complicated)

In Java 9 you might be able to use user defined intrinsics.  This will allow you to add assembly into Java to use instructions Java doesn't currently use like XMM.

Comment: To clarify, you'd have to send the values to the C/ASM code in parameters and get the result back as a return value (or using a result collector). The code will not have direct access to the Java variables.

Comment: @Andreas I agree, in fact the Java variables might not make any sense to a C/ASM code as they could be stored in any manner (or even optimized away to nothing) +1